# Select an entity in a form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

For my website , I had to make a " ManyToMany " by hand because my entity receives custom fields. In addition, the " ManyToMany " points to itself ( self- referencing ) . To simply explain : I have a page for adding modules ( that, it works ), and when I add modules , I can select the modules to link previously recorded . :)

Here is my entity Module AdministrationBundle \ Entity \ Module:

```
...

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AdministrationBundle\Entity\ModuleModuleLie", mappedBy="module")
 */
private $modules;

public function addModule(\AdministrationBundle\Entity\Module $module)
{
    $this->modules[] = $module;
    return $this;
}

public function removeModule(\AdministrationBundle\Entity\Module $module)
{
    $this->modules->removeElement($module);
}
```

Here is my entity AdministrationBundle Module \ Entity \ ModuleModuleLie ( the join table ) :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdministrationBundle\Entity\Module", inversedBy="modules")
*/
protected $module;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdministrationBundle\Entity\Module")
*/
protected $moduleLie;

public function setModule(\AdministrationBundle\Entity\Module $module)
{
    $this->module = $module;
}

public function getModule()
{
    return $this->moduleLie;
}

public function setModuleLie(\AdministrationBundle\Entity\Module $module)
{
    $this->module = $module;
}

public function getModuleLie()
{
    return $this->moduleLie;
}
```

Finally , I have my form that appears correctly in particular listing the previously stored modules:

```
    $builder
 ->add('modules', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AdministrationBundle\Entity\Module',
                'property' => 'libelle',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Module(s) importé(s)'
            )
        );
```

However, during the validation I have this error that I can not solve :

"Found the type of entity AdministrationBundle \ Entity \ Module combination is AdministrationBundle \ Entity \ # Module modules , purpose expecting AdministrationBundle \ Entity \ ModuleModuleLie "

Any ideas ?